# When is it possible to partition $n(n-1)/2$ pairs of $\{i,j\}$ into $n-1$ sets such that in each set each number appears once?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider an even number $n$. There are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pairs of $\{i,j\}$ with $1 \leq i < j \leq n$. Consider the following problem. The goal is to allocate each pair of $\{i,j\}$ to $n-1$ subsets such that each subset contains $\frac{n}{2}$ pairs. Moreover, in each subset, I want each element from $1$ to $n$ to appear once (and only once). I want to know when is this partition possible, and is there an algorithm to find it?

For example, when $n = 4$, a partition satisfying the requirement is
$\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, $\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$ and $\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}$. All numbers appear in each subset once.

Comment: Hint: Draw the complete graph with vertices evenly spaced on a circle. Then, there's a "natural" way to select $n/2$ pairs such that each number appears once. We can do this $n-1$ times (and the way explains why the pairs are uniquely chosen).

Comment: @CalvinLin Could you elaborate a bit more? By "natural" way, do you mean fixing the distance between each node in the pair? (I can't think of other natural way.) Then how about the following situation? Let $n=12$. We first pair up $(1,5)$, $(2,6)$, $(3,7)$ and $(4,8)$. Then $(9,1)$... but wait... $1$ has already been paired up with $5$. Or you could consider another way to proceed $(1,5)$, $(6,10)$, $(11,3)$, $(4,8)$ then $(9,1)$ again, still not working...

Comment: Show that for a given edge, there are $n/2$ parallel edges (inclusive of the one we started with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's always possible. This is simply the scheduling of pairings of an n-person round-robin tournament and has been answered before.

For n = 4, in your example, place the numbers initially as:

1  4
2  3

Keep the 1 fixed, and rotate the other numbers clockwise.

Comment: Thanks. I found it on wikipedia.